# How do I prevent a pod IP:port combination from being accessible?

Tags: kubernetes, network-programming

I have a container that I don't want to be accessed except through a gateway that checks for authorization. The gateway works great if you are accessing the container through the gateway service. However, if I curl the pod IP:port combination to access the container I want protected the request is allowed through with nothing stopping it. I have tried configuring a simple NetworkPolicy to prevent this access by using the basic example here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/ specifically the example at the bottom of the page where you deny everything for Ingress and Egress. That network policy still did not prevent the curl to the pod IP:port combination. What am I missing or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What sort of networking are you using in your cluster? Not every CNI enforces NetworkPolicy.

Comment: Can you confirm the networking solution used !! for network policy to work its required to have a networking solution which supports NetworkPolicy settings.

Comment: Where is the gateway running - outside or inside of the cluster? If it is inside the same cluster - is it in a different namespace than the service it is protecting? Is the gateway intended to protect just this service or others as well?

Comment: So I am using a kubeadm install of kubernetes, calico for networking and the gateway is running inside the same pod. When I configured the NetworkPolicy for deny all ingress and egress I was able to confirm that the gateway no longer allowed access to the container. Thank you all for commenting so quickly!

Comment: If you managed to solve it could you post you solution as an answer for better community visibility?